# Using mathjaxr to get nice display in r package documentation

Tags: r, mathjax, r-package

I'm having difficulties with the mathjaxr package to get nice display in the documentation of **my first package**.

I followed instructions given here : https://rdrr.io/github/wviechtb/mathjaxr/man/mathjaxr-package.html

Here is what I put in my R file before the function :

```
#' Probabilistic principal component analysis :
#' parameter estimation with EM algorithm
#'
#' @param Y les données : une matrice de taille n x p
#' @param Gamma0 point de départ pour l'inférence de Gamma
#'
#' @return la fonction renvoie la moyenne d'un vecteur
#' @import mvtnorm
#' @import psych
#' @import mathjaxr
#' @description 
#' \loadmathjax
#' \mjdeqn{f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}#\right)^2},}
#' {f(x) = 1/(sqrt(2 pi) sigma) e^-((x - mu)^2/(2 sigma^2)),}
```

And here is what I have in my description file :

```
Package: ppcaem
Title: Parameter estimation in ppca model with EM algorithm
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: 
    person(given = "First",
           family = "Last",
           role = c("aut", "cre"),
           email = "first.last@example.com",
           comment = c(ORCID = "YOUR-ORCID-ID"))
Description: cf title
RdMacros: mathjaxr
License: GPL-3
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Imports: 
    psych,
    mvtnorm,
    mathjaxr
RoxygenNote: 7.1.1
```

And here is the rendered :

[mathjaxr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dlf5a.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried without using roxygen and it works, if it can help..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace `\mjdeqn` with `\mjsdeqn`:

```
#' Probabilistic principal component analysis :
#' parameter estimation with EM algorithm
#'
#' @param Y les données : une matrice de taille n x p
#' @param Gamma0 point de départ pour l'inférence de Gamma
#'
#' @return la fonction renvoie la moyenne d'un vecteur
#' @import mvtnorm
#' @import psych
#' @import mathjaxr
#' @description 
#' \loadmathjax
#' \mjsdeqn{f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}#\right)^2},}
#' {f(x) = 1/(sqrt(2 pi) sigma) e^-((x - mu)^2/(2 sigma^2)),}
```